# GUI help in java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I created a password verifier app using JOptionPane but now i need to convert it to a GUI app. Please help, i need it in order to pass one of my classes. Also, i need to complete it today. I know I'm doing it completely wrong. This is both classes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



/**
   Demo program for the PasswordVerifier class
   Chapter 10
   Programming Challenge 5, Password Verifier
*/

public class PasswordDemo extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    private final JTextArea message;
    private final JTextArea invalidInput;
    private final JTextField input;
    private final ButtonGroup group;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;

    /**
     *  Constructor
     */
    private PasswordDemo()
    {
        setTitle("Password Demo");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);



       // group = getGroupPane();
       // group.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

      message = new JTextArea("enter pass");
        message.setOpaque(false);
        message.setEditable(false);

        invalidInput = new JTextArea("");
        invalidInput.setOpaque(false);
        invalidInput.setEditable(false);
        invalidInput.setForeground(Color.red);





        input = new JTextField(10);

        //group.add(input);
        //group.add(invaldInput);
        //group.add( message );


        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(message);
        panel.add(input);


          PasswordVerifier pv = new PasswordVerifier();

        input.addActionListener((ActionListener) pv);
    }




  private class PasswordVerifier implements ActionListener
    {
       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e)
       {
           String input;

           if(!PasswordVerifier.isValid(input)) {
              invalidInput.append("The password does not meet the requirements."); 
           }
           else{
               invalidInput.append("Good choice buddy");
           }


       }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        PasswordDemo passwordDemo = new PasswordDemo();
}
}






public class PasswordVerifier{

// Minimum password length
private static final int MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 7;  

    /**
     * The isValid method determines whether a password is valid or not.
     *
     * @param str A string to test as a password.
     * @return true if the string contains a valid password, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isValid(String str) {
        boolean status = false;

        PasswordVerifier pass = new PasswordVerifier();

        if (PasswordVerifier.hasUpperCase(str) && PasswordVerifier.hasLowerCase(str) 
                && PasswordVerifier.hasDigit(str)) {
            status = true;
        }

        if (str.length() < 7) {
            status = false;
        }

        return status;
    }

    /**
     * The hasUpperCase method determines whether a string has at least one
     * uppercase character.
     *
     * @param str A string to test.
     * @return true if the string contains an uppercase character, false
     * otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean hasUpperCase(String str) {
        boolean status = false; 
        int i = 0;
        while (i < str.length()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                status = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * The hasLowerCase method determines whether a string has at least one
     * lowercase character.
     *
     * @param str A string to test.
     * @return true if the string contains an lowercase character, false
     * otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean hasLowerCase(String str) {
        boolean status = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < str.length()) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) {
                status = true;
                break;
            }

            i++;
        }
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * The hasDigit method determines whether a string has at least one numeric
     * digit.
     *
     * @param str A string to test.
     * @return true if the string contains a numeric digit, false otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean hasDigit(String str) {
        boolean status = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < str.length()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {

                status = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return status;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is Java not JavaScript.

Comment: Lol yea i i don't know why i selected javascript it sorry